# stacked bar charts using html 5 by reading values from an array

Tags: html, bar-chart

Want to plot a stacked bar chart in Rgraph .I want to show the graph based on the values from an array.Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really a bunch of APIs out there. For instance the [google chart tools](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html). Or google for some [jquery plugins](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+chart+library).